# Loading Xml file into XDocument to later use in a Button

Tags: xml, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, xml-parsing

I've currently been using the following code to load a large Xml file into an XTable:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
  TextBox4.Visible = False
  Dim asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  Dim var = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication2.british-english-dictionary.xml")

  Dim rand = New Random()
  Dim myXml = XDocument.Load(var)
  var.Close()

  Dim lexemeList = myXml.Descendants("lexeme").ToList()
  Dim randomLexeme = lexemeList(rand.Next(0, lexemeList.Count - 1))

  TextBox2.Text = randomLexeme.Descendants("grapheme").Value
End Sub
```

However, as the xml is quite long (400,000 entries) there is a bit of a delay on the button press. To try and minimise it i'd like to take the `Dim myXml = XDocument.Load(var)` outside of the button press so that the loading of the Xml file to the XDocument is only done on opening the program, not every time the button is pressed.

I have tried doing this:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Security.Permissions

Public Class Form1    
  Public asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  Public var = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication2.british-english-dictionary.xml")

  Public rand = New Random()
  Public myXml = XDocument.Load(var)

  Private Sub Button5_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    TextBox4.Visible = False

    Dim lexemeList = myXml.Descendants("lexeme").ToList()
    Dim randomLexeme = lexemeList(rand.Next(0, lexemeList.Count - 1))

    TextBox2.Text = randomLexeme.Descendants("grapheme").Value
  End Sub
End Class
```

But I receive an error when the Button click event occurs:

> Public member 'ToList' on type 'd__a' not found.

Answer (score 4):

You should not be doing any heavy work in variable initializers. Instead, use `Sub New` or `Form_Load`. Always explicitly specify type and give your variables a meaningful name. Avoid unnecessary exposure of variables, for example `asm` can be private within `Sub New`. For example:

```vb
Public var As Stream
Public rand As Random
Public myXml As XDocument

Sub New()
  ' This call is required by the designer.
  InitializeComponent()

  ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
  Dim asm As Assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
  var = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("WindowsApplication2.british-english-dictionary.xml")
  rand = New Random()
  myXml = XDocument.Load(var)
End Sub
```

Start with that, and see if the error still persists.

As a side note, you could make your code more simple, if you add a resource file to your project (*.resx), and then add your XML resource to it. Then it becomes as simple as calling:

```
myXml = XDocument.Load(My.Resources.ResxName.british-english-dictionary.xml)
```

Notice resource names are checked at compile time, and VS does the plumbing for you.